# Tensorflow bert tokenize unknown words

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently doing the following tf tutorial : https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/solve_glue_tasks_using_bert_on_tpu

Testing the outputs of the tokenize function on different sentences, I wonder what happens when tokenizing unknown words.

Loading model:

```
bert_model_name = 'bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12' 
tfhub_handle_encoder = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/3'
tfhub_handle_preprocess = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3'
bert_preprocess = hub.load(tfhub_handle_preprocess)
```

Tokenizing sentence/word:

```
tok = bert_preprocess.tokenize(tf.constant(['Tensorsss bla']))
print(tok)

# Output:
<tf.RaggedTensor [[[23435, 4757, 2015], [1038, 2721]]]>
```

Shouldnt it be so every word is tokenized to a single token ? Those are obviously made up words, but I am wondering what happens when you encode those words to fixed length vectors.

Also, how does the tokenizer transform the made up words in 3 different tokens ? Does it split the unknown words into different known parts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default cache location for the `tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3` model is `/tmp/tfhub_modules/602d30248ff7929470db09f7385fc895e9ceb4c0` ([more on caching](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/caching)). In the `assets` directory, you'll find `vocab.txt`, which is the used vocabulary. You can use the file to look up what token the token-id `i` corresponds to by looking at line `i+1` of the file i.e.

```sh
sed '23436q;d' /tmp/tfhub_modules/602d30248ff7929470db09f7385fc895e9ceb4c0/assets/vocab.txt
> tensor
```

Doing that for all token-ids returns

```
[tensor, ##ss, ##s], [b, ##la]
```

As you can see, this confirms your theory that words are split into different known parts. More details on the exact algorithm can be found in [Subword tokenizers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/tensorflow_text/subwords_tokenizer).